# Как подключить файл со стилями CSS

Tags: html, css

Не хочу указывать стили изначально в `index.html`.

Насколько понял - их можно засунуть в папку как файл `css/style.css`

И просто вызвать в `<head>` и не прописывать в ручную.

Но у  меня почему то не выходит.

Текст остается таким же как и был.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>HUB</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/cloud.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        </head>

        <style>
        </style>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точнее не получается его вызвать.
Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: @Sevastopol' Почему то все равно страницу не изменилась...
https://i.imgur.com/s0NAZl0.png

Comment: @Zekoy <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css"> Две точки перед слешем добавьте, что означает подъем на один уровень вверх относительно index.html

Comment: @Sevastopol' на картинке видно, где папка CSS

Comment: Одно из двух: либо проблема в самих стилях, либо кириллица в названиях папок/файлов (например, буква С в _c_ss).

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало.

Comment: @Zekoy обществу интересно, где была ошибка?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">` Сам не до конца понял почему она возникла. Но вот вроде указав так - все заработало.